# Exception after 49 records in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I am writing a simple application that stores data into Elasticsearch via Kafka Consumer. My problem is that whenever I execute the same consumer App, it is throwing an exception after processing 40 or 50 records. The exception description says that the limit of total fields has been exceeded index (1000). What I have learned that the default value (entries) in Elasticsearch is 1000 but in my case, it is way below 1000.

I am adding the exception below, thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

`Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [https://kafka-poject-twitter-8210391326.eu-west-1.bonsaisearch.net:443], URI [/twitter/tweets?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [twitter] has been exceeded"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [twitter] has been exceeded"},"status":400} at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:920) at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:227) at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1256)`

Comment: can you show your mapping and sample doc which you are ingesting ?

Comment: I am just storing tweets from the twitter developer API. Is it possible due to the length of the tweets (Some are very long)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Reason - `Limit of total fields [1000] in index [twitter] has been exceeded`

You can overcome this by increasing the limit

```
PUT twitter/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```

Comment: Hey @Gibbs, Thanks it worked. Quick question, why was it throwing the exception after 30-40 records whereas now it has processed all the records.
Thanks

Comment: Because at 30-40 seconds, your field limit crossed the default value `1024` - `Kafka portioning` made it faster and appropriate at a particular interval - hope you were resetting group Id every run / starting from the beginning.

Comment: I wasn't changing the group id but I did after changing the index limit to 2000 and it processed all the records.

Comment: ok, I guess your application processes more than 1024 fields in 30-40 seconds.

Comment: @SimranSingh Was my answer helpful? If so, will you approve that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is not related with the number of documents (tweet) you're inserting but the number of different field names contained in such documents.

As explained in Elasticsearch's documentation:

> The limit is in place to prevent mappings and searches from becoming too large. Higher values can lead to performance degradations and memory issues, especially in clusters with a high load or few resources.

Even though you can increase this limit, it's probably not the solution to your problem. Given you reached the limit of 1000 inserting just 50 records, even if you increase it you might very rapidly reach the new limit once again.

To fix the issue you should do some preprocessing to the JSON you're storing in Elasticsearch ensuring that only the relevant fields are indexed. For instance given you're indexing tweets, I would expect the documents to have a schema like the following:

```
{
  "author": ...,
  "timestamp": ...,
  "tweet": ...
}
```

With such a schema you limit the number of field Elasticsearch must keep track of to just 3 independently of the number of records you write.

You can enforce the schema of the document you're inserting in Elasticsearch using [Index Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) setting the strict properties. This way you will get an error if by error you have unwanted fields in the documents you're trying to index.

Comment: Ok, I will try this approach as well. I did change the setting Index: 2000 and I am able to process all the tweets now. I am not using the latest version (7.8) which you had mentioned in your answer.